# Flutter text inside container

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i've created container(2) inside container(1). Can you please help how to add text to the container(1)? Here is my code down below

```
    return Scaffold(
  body: 
  Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100, left: 30, right: 30, bottom: 25,),
    child: Container(
      height: 300,
      color: Colors.red,
      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      child: Container(
        width: 360,
        height: 230,
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text(
            'Car or sport car'
            maxLines: 3,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: you can use any [multi-child layout widget](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/layout#Multi-child%20layout%20widgets) according to your requirement and set Text into your container(1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to put a `Column, Row or Stack` inside the first `Container`. Here is an example for your understanding.

```
return Scaffold(
body: 
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100, left: 30, right: 30, bottom: 25,),
  child: Container(
    height: 300,
    color: Colors.red,
    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text("Put your Text Here!!!!"),
        Container(
        width: 360,
        height: 230,
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text(
            'Car or sport car'
            maxLines: 3,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),]
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    return Scaffold(
  body: 
  Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100, left: 30, right: 30, bottom: 25,),
    child: Container(
      height: 300,
      color: Colors.red,
      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      child: Column(children:[
        Text('test'),
        Container(
        width: 360,
        height: 230,
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text(
            'Car or sport car'
            maxLines: 3,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```